# Tkinter Frame container color not visible

Tags: python, tkinter

Why can't I see a red frame with the following code?

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("220x300")

container_frame = Tkinter.Frame(background = "red", width = 100, height = 120)
container_frame.pack()

widget_button = Tkinter.Button(master = container_frame)
widget_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, you need to set container_frame's master to root...

Comment: Strangely this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't see it because you have no padding between the button and the frame. By default, containers "shrink to fit" around their contents. Even if you add an explicit width or height to the frame, it will shrink to exactly fit its children.

There are several ways to achieve the effect you're looking for, but it's not clear exactly what effect you want. You can turn off this "shrink-to-fit" behavior (using `container_frame.pack_propagate(False)`). Or, you can add padding around the widget. Or, you can apply the background to the container of the frame. Or you could pack the frame to fill its container (the main window), then make sure the containing window is large enough to expose the frame.

For an example of that last suggestion, you can change one line to be this:

```
container_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! You said "Or, you can apply the background to the container of the frame.". I tried `root = Tkinter.Tk(background = "red")` . That didn't work, how should I do that? I also did `frame_container.overriderderict()`. This produced an AttributeError.

Comment: @Bentley4: I don't know what I was thinking when I posted my answer, I completely mislead you. You don't want `overrideredirect`, you want `pack_propagate`. Sorry for the confusion; I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you change to:

```
widget_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

You can see that the frame has been resized when call widget_button.pack(...)

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, this just provides padding to the button, it doesn't answer the question. I know Frame resizes by default to the size of the widgets who call `container_frame` as an argument of their instantiation. But I passed the options: `width=100` and `height=120` to override this behavior. So I would like to get the `container_frame` to get this size and see it by having a color.